# Every real polynomial attains a smallest absolute value

Tags: calculus

Let $p$ be any real polynomial. Show there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|p(c)| \leq|p(x)|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I believe you mean p(c),p(x)

Comment: Let p(x)=x, then there is -no- c such that c=p(c)<=p(x)=x for all real numbers x.

Comment: @mathematician you are forgetting the absolute value. $c=0$ works for your e.g.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

1) If $p(x)$ is an odd polynomial, it has a real root (say $c$) and hence $0 = |p(c )| \le |f(x)|$.

2) If $p(x)$ has even degree, WLOG let the leading coefficient be positive.  Then we see that $p(x)$ approaches $\infty$ on both ends of the axis.  This implies that if we pick a number $M$ larger than some element of the range of $p(x)$, we have a closed interval $[a, b]$ where $p(x)>M$ outside this interval.

As $[a, b]$ is compact and $p$ is continuous, so it attains a minimum at say $c$. Now it is easy to show $|p(c )| \le |f(x)|$.

Answer (score 2):

For any polynomial $p(x)$, the function $\vert p(x) \vert$ is continuous and satisfies $\vert p(x) \vert \to \infty$ as $\vert x \vert \to \infty$.  Given that this is the case, it is evident that this question is in fact a special case of this one: [problem about continuity and limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422382/problem-about-continuity-and-limits), and the solution given there by, of all people, Yours Truly, covers the present question as well.

Whew!  Saved some single-finger 'droid typing!

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

#### Hint:

Every polynomial is either constant or not. If it's not, it must have a certain sort of behavior for arguments with very large absolute values. The local behavior of polynomials also has a useful property.